# Email como primary key

Tags: banco-de-dados

Criei um Banco de Dados, e nos cursos que fiz sempre usávamos o id como *primary key*,tem problema usar o e-mail como sendo a chave primária, porque dessa forma impediria o cadastro de um e-mail igual!

Comment: Só se usar o email como username, porque se usar um email e um username vai acontecer de poder usar vários username com o mesmo nome

Comment: Conforme é mostrado na pergunta duplicata pode usar e-mail, mas não deve, e não é pelo motivo que citaram nas respostas abaixo. É porque ele pode ser mudado, pode ser usado por mais de uma pessoa, pode ser que a pessoa queria ter dois cadastros, porque você não não controle, porque ele tende ser mais longo do que deveria para uma chave primária, porque nem todo mundo tem e-mail ou quer fornecer um, e a lista continua. Lá tem um *link* mostrando que em geral as pessoas não entendem as implicações de usar um determinado dado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não há problema em utilizar o email como `PRIMARY KEY`, porém, não é recomendado.

Há uma maneira de evitar que um dado seja registrado mais de uma vez, para isso você pode informar, durante a criação da tabela, o valor **[UNIQUE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `nome` int(60) NOT NULL,
  `idade` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Caso você já tenha criado sua tabela.

```
ALTER TABLE `usuarios` ADD UNIQUE(`email`);
```

Comment: Valeu cara, muito obrigado mesmo, não tinha pensado por esse lado, realmente ia ser um problema!!